# Remove the last character typed in UItextfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitextfield

I need to remove the last character if the textfield length exceeds 100,I used the following code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textfield.text.length>=100)
    {
        NSString *text;
        textField.text=text;
        NSString *newString = [text substringToIndex:[text length]-1];
        textField.text=newString;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

But it just erases the whole text.

Comment: Can you explain the desired result a bit more? What if the text field contains 110 characters? And what if the text field contains 99 characters the user pastes 10 characters from the clipboard? Also if the last character was `a` and the user adds `b` at the end of the string, would you like to remove `a` or `b`?

Comment: accept the answer if your problem is solved , people have wasted their  time for solving your mistake , respect it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You erase the whole text because of this line:

```
textField.text=text; // text is nil here
```

What you wanted to do is more likely the following:

```
NSString *text = textField.text;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

      if(textfield.text.length>=100)
     {
         NSString *text;
         text =[[textField text] stringByAppendingString:string];
         NSString *newString = [text substringToIndex:[text length]-1];

         textField.text=newString;
     }
     return YES;

 }
```

Paste the code may solve your issue

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 5 or later:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([textField.text length] >= 100)
    {
        [textField deleteBackward];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try with the below code

```
 - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)aRange replacementText:(NSString *)aText {

    NSString* newText = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:aRange withString:aText];

    // CGSize strSize = [newText sizeWithFont:textView.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 10000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

   if([newText length] > 100)
   {
       return NO; // can't enter more text
   }
   else
      return YES; // let the textView know that it should handle the inserted text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
return !([newString length] >100);
}
```

Comment: @sch textField.text=[textField.text substringToIndex:[textField.text length]-1]

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the `UITextField` length you don't have to work with strings concatenation. Just use this simple code:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    return !([string length]+[textField.text length] > FIXED_LENGTH);

}
```

This way you, as `UITextFieldDelegate`, are saying: "change the `UITextField` appending `string` to `textField.text` **only** if the sum of all characters doesn't exceed max length"

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to remove any text in UITextField; applies to iOS 10.3 and later

```
@IBOutlet var upcText: UITextField!
if var textRange = upcText.selectedTextRange {
    if textRange.isEmpty && textRange.start != upcText.beginningOfDocument {
        // text has not been selected and the cursor is not at the beginnning
        // then create new range to delete previous character
        textRange = upcText.textRange(from: upcText.position(from: textRange.start, offset: -1)!, to: textRange.start)!
    }
    upcText.replace(textRange, withText: "")
}
```